# Force DIV's that start in a new row to sit directly underneath the DIV above

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I would like to remove the white gaps underneath each DIV so that they are positioned directly underneath, and not with a large white gap which is caused by the DIV on the row above that has the largest height:

I am currently using the following CSS

```
.extmar {
    height: auto !important; 
    margin-bottom:25px; 
    display:inline-block !important; 
    float:left !important; 
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    vertical-align: top !important;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/3u3z5quk/

I have attached an image of what I am aiming to replicate[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WfgDu.png).

Comment: That's called masonry layout - if you google it there's lots of ways to do it with css and with javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found this on JSFiddle for you : https://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/tQANc/

**I do not made this code** but I think you can try it with your case.

The interesting part :

```
#container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 700px;
    margin: 2em auto;
}
.cols {
    -moz-column-count:3;
    -moz-column-gap: 3%;
    -moz-column-width: 30%;
    -webkit-column-count:3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 3%;
    -webkit-column-width: 30%;
    column-count: 3;
    column-gap: 3%;
    column-width: 30%;
}
.box {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

If you have questions about this code, I can explain it to you.

Comment: Hi Vincent, that's fantastic. Thanks so much for this. Works great!

Comment: No problem, I did not made this code, we should thanks the owner ;)